# Force Reload VS soution Explorer when adding new c# Script via Unity3d?

Tags: unity, visual-studio

When I create C# script (`Create -> C# Script`) via `Unity3d`  or delete it from `Unity3d` - `Visual Studio` shows me the warning window.

[image]

it's annoying.

Is there any way to force "ReloadAll" in solution Explorer without the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what we have.

Developer from the `VS Tools for Unity team` [said](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-disable-visual-studio-dialog-file-modification-detected.364919/#post-2482822) that it is one of their most voted feature requests.
 And it's surprisingly not trivial to fix, they are working on it.

However, I found some script which can use.. I found it on [russian unity community](http://unity3d.ru/distribution/viewtopic.php?p=249649).

Great thanks to **DbIMok**.
Also he posted this script yesterday on [forum.unity3d.com](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-disable-visual-studio-dialog-file-modification-detected.364919/#post-2690972)

Need to create C# script named as `FileModDialogCloser.cs` and put it into the `Editor` folder.
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEditor;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class FileModDialogCloser {

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

        const string search = "File Modification Detected";
        static IntPtr hwnd;

        static void Check() { 
                hwnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, search);
                if ((int)hwnd != 0) {
                        ShowWindow(hwnd, 5);
                        keybd_event(0x0D, 0, 0, 0);
                }
        }

        static FileModDialogCloser() {
                EditorApplication.update += Check;
        }
}
```

Wondering!

It works for creating and deleting C# scripts via Unity.

As you can see the code has a line `keybd_event(0x0D, 0, 0, 0);`. This is simulate pressing of <kbd>Enter</kbd> button. And that means *Reload* realization. if you need *ReloadAll* then you have to do like that:

```
keybd_event(0x09, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(0x0D, 0, 0, 0);
```

This is pressing of <kbd>Tab</kbd> button and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

*SMALL FAULT:* When you are creating/deleting script: confirm window opens, runs `keybd_event`, the window closes. It happen very fast, so you don't need to click any button. But you can see this window on few milliseconds anyway. 
I think, for now there is no better way to do that.

---

**ADDITIONALLY:**

You can create C# script **for Unity projects** (not just simple C# script) within `Visual Studio`. `Unity` will add the file automatically without confirmation window.

**The first method (simlple)**:

If I got it right: when you are using `Visual Studio Tools for Unity` - that tool are integrating already templates for creating Unity C# scripts into the `VS`. 
So, right click on Solution and chose `Add -> NewItem`. You can see two templates for Unity:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

However, these templates can contains a lot of unnecessary information, comments for example `// Use this for initialization`, `// Update is called once per frame` e.t.c.
And, as @wondra in comments [said](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/124320/force-reload-vs-soution-explorer-when-adding-new-c-script-via-unity3d#comment217641_124324):  you can add own custom item template for unity scripts.

**The second method**:

- Creating file from anywhere.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Adding whatever you want or delete smth., or example:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Click `File -> ExportTemplate`

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Choose `ItemTemlate`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Check your template in the list

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Click `Next`, `Next`
- Set name and description for template, click `Finish`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Template will be added into the `c:\Users\YOUR_PROFILE\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\My Exported Templates\` folder, also into the `c:\Users\YOUR_PROFILE\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ItemTemplates\`. 
  After `VS` restart you can see this template in the list just as `VS Tools for Unity` templates:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Here is the [video explanation](https://youtu.be/bTxCNS1DNUs).

---

Happy End!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the new script directly on Visual Studio on your intended directory in Unity. In that case you will not need to reload.
[image]

But you will have to do something else. New script in Visual Studio will have some namespaces that used default. You may change or remove them. You will have to add `using UnityEngine;`at first for Unity related privileges. You will have to add `void Start()` or `void Update()` by yourself if you need.
New Class should look like:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I know that. But sometimes I want to create/delete scripts within Unity

Comment: You dont have to add using UnityEngine or start()/stop() manually, you can add own custom [item template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx) for unity scripts.